# How do I play a video using Red5?

Tags: video-streaming, red5, jwplayer, rtmp

I had my hosting company install Red5 on my server and they sent me the address and the ports for the RMS and RMS HTTP protocols. So how do I actually upload a video and embed it in a webpage for playback? Is there a premade application I can use or do I have to create one myself? I can't find anything in the documentation but development code.

Edit: Looks like I can use JWPlayer to play the videos via RTMP. Is there a specific folder I need to upload the videos to, or can I put them anywhere on the Red5 server e.g. rtmp://myip/red5/myvideos/video1.mp4 ?

Edit: I've added the [Video Whisper application](http://www.videowhisper.com/?p=RTMP%20Applications) to my webapps directory and moved the file to the videowhisperstreams directory, but still no luck (the JWPlayer shows, but the server can't be found) Here's my code:

```
<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer('mediaspace').setup({
  'flashplayer': 'jwplayer/player.swf',
  'file': 'test.flv',
  'streamer': 'rtmp://myip/videowhisper',
  'controlbar': 'bottom',
  'width': '470',
  'height': '290'
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The above script does work, but I was uploading the app and video to `/root/red5/webapps` instead of `<root>/opt/red5/webapps`

Comment: Your videos themselves need to go in "streams" unless youve got your own custom filename generator. So in your case the path would be something like this /opt/red5/webapps/[your app name]/streams

Answer (score 0):

try this.. Download jwplayer swfobject.js  , player.swf

http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/

Upload video

http://hioxindia.com/faq/domain-hosting/Install-Flash-Media-Encoder.php

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='swfobject.js'></script>

<div id='mediaspace'>This text will be replaced</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var url='rtmp://myip/red5/myvideos/video1.mp4';
var so = new SWFObject('player.swf','mpl','550','400','9');

so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');

so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');

so.addParam('wmode','opaque');

so.addVariable('file','livestream.flv');

so.addVariable('plugins','livestream-1');

so.addVariable('streamer',url);

so.write('mediaspace');

</script>
```